# Assign column under another column mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
project.sql
projectNo| title |
---------+-------+
17020002 | test  |
17020003 | test2 |

process.sql
projectNo| process | 
---------+---------+
17020002 | ANM     |
17020002 | BLD     |
17020003 | ANM KEY |
17020003 | BLD     |
```

Is there any way to create html table from mysql query which will look like this:

```
|         |
+---------+
| test    |
| ANM     |
| BLD     |
| test2   |
| ANM KEY | 
| BLD     |
```

What I tried is to use UNION ALL but it doesnt give me desired outcome:

```
SELECT title FROM project p1
UNION ALL
SELECT process FROM process p2
```

Comment: Your desired outcome, did you mean the order of the result?

Comment: @Forward yes, it just give me union of to columns, without any order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a fixed column to sort result, try this:

```
SELECT title
FROM (
    SELECT projectNo, title, 0 AS a FROM project p1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT projectNo, process, 1 AS a FROM process p2) t
ORDER BY projectNo, a, title
```